# When did a Jew last marry a woman captured in war?

Tags: history, marriage, army-military-war

What is the last recorded case of a Jew marrying a woman captured in war, as allowed by the Torah [Deut. 21:10-14]?  Anybody more recent than King David, as mentioned in Sanhedrin 21a and Kiddushin 76b?

Comment: I thought there was a case when also with David Hamelech with Michal when Shaul gave her to him before battle with Golias hence Avshalom “Ben sorrer u’moreh”

Comment: @DanielRoss Michal was the daughter of Shaul. That was a regular married and Avshalom was not her son.

Comment: on a side note: the story in kiddushin, as quite clear from the mefarshim there, was not dovid hamelech himself marrying captive women. rather he had "troops"(see gem. there why the quotes) from jews that married captive women

Comment: @Sabbhaillel sorry my mistake it could then be Maacah daughter of Talmai King of Geshur (Tanchuma Ki Seitzei 1)

Comment: To VTCers: Why is history of a (seemingly) relatively sparingly performed Mitzvah off-topic?